# Firebase no reconoce valores

Tags: android, firebase

llevo dias con este problema espero me puedan ayudar :)

Tengo un codigo en Android Studio donde me conecto a Firebase, en la cual subo valores, modifico y los traigo.
He probado mi aplicacion y funciona bien para unos valores, luego para otro valor no funciona y luego para otros valores si, y asi sucesivamente. No entiendo el porque pasaria eso si el codigo es el mismo para todos los valores.
Dejo aqui el codigo para su visualizacion, gracias :)

Los metodos recolectar() y recuperar() son metodos donde asigno a un ArrayList los numeros 1 y 0 dependiendo si se presionaron una cantidad de Radio Buttons,
1 es si se presiono el Radio button y el 0 es si no se presiono.

```
 public void metodo_subir(View v) {

    recolectar();// recolecta los numeros delos RadioButtons
    codigoos=ArrayPostvaciado.toString();
    mRootReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String todo = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
                if (todo.contains("LiberaPostvaciado")) {
                    if (todo.contains(ubicacion)) {
                        if (todo.contains(elemento)) {
                            p = 1;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    p = 0;
                }
            }
            if (p == 0) {
                subir(codigoos);
            } else if (p == 1) {
                modificaar(codigoos);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });

}
public void subir(String codigoos){

    Map<String, Object> datosLibPostvaciado = new HashMap<>();
    datosLibPostvaciado.put("Elemento", elemento);
    datosLibPostvaciado.put("Procedimiento", procedimiento);
    datosLibPostvaciado.put("Ubicacion", ubicacion);
    datosLibPostvaciado.put("Codigo", codigoos);
    mRootReference.child("LiberaPostvaciado").push().setValue(datosLibPostvaciado);
}
public void modificaar(String codigoos) {
    final String codigoooos=codigoos;
    Query q = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("LiberaPostvaciado").orderByChild("Elemento").equalTo(elemento);
    q.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                //if el recorrido contiene a la ubicacion cojo ese key y en ese key cambio el status
                String recorrido = snapshot.getValue().toString();
                if (recorrido.contains(ubicacion)) {
                    klave = snapshot.getKey();
                }
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("LiberaPostvaciado").child(klave).child("Codigo").setValue(codigoooos);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}
```

Aqui el metodo donde traigo los datos desde el Firebase

```
public void metodo_cargar_data(View v){  //METODO DONDE TRAIGO LOS DATOS DESDE EL FIREBASE

    mRootReference.child("LiberaPostvaciado").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String todo = snapshot.getValue().toString();
                if (todo.contains(elemento)){
                    if (todo.contains(ubicacion)){
                        PojoLibVaciado pojo = snapshot.getValue(PojoLibVaciado.class);
                        String codiggos=pojo.getCodigo();
                        recuperar(codiggos);
                    }
                }
            }}
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });

}
```

Asi se muestra el Firebase:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Los valores aparecen truncados en la imagen o son realmente así?  Por ejemplo ¿ `Post-Vaciado`  cierra con una comilla `"`?, ¿por qué cierras los valores en `Elemento` con una comilla simple y no con una doble? Realmente los datos se guardan como un JSON, no debes violar las normas. ¿`Codigo` es un array o qué es?

Comment: podrias colocar el codigo de recuperar, el codigo de PojoLibVaciado  y que es el tipo de dato ubicaciones dentro de contains(ubicaciones) gracias